# Clojure Worksheets

Tags: clojure

I have been learning Clojure a bit recently. Is there such a thing in Clojure world as Scala-like worksheets, into which I can put any code and get it evaluated as soon as I save it? Or maybe there's a similar solution for Clojure?

I am now working with lein repl and, sadly, can't say it's the most usable tool ever.

Comment: You might want to check out Light Table. It's still in a rather early stage, but already fairly usable.

PS: What's your problem with lein repl though? The only problem I'd have with it is the lack of syntax highlighting, which can be avoided by running a nREPL client in emacs (or anything else really)

Comment: For a very simple Clojure environment that doesn't take any time to setup I'd recommend trying [Clooj](https://github.com/arthuredelstein/clooj). Written on Clojure for Clojure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Lisp development in general (and Clojure in particular) the preferred programming style is what's usually dubbed *interactive programming* - the developer keeps an image of the app loaded at all times and interacts with it via a REPL. You can easily modify the loaded code on the fly and test changes immediately in the REPL (that's not easy at all with Scala - one has to resort to something like [JRebel](http://batsov.com/articles/2011/04/26/jrebel-with-scala/) to do it). I find the Scala worksheets a pretty primitive solution in comparison...

The workflow that I follow in Clojure is:

1. I open [nREPL.el](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el) in Emacs - this loads my lein2 project with all of its dependencies and gives me a REPL which I can use the try out stuff
2. I write some code in source code and load the changed functions (maybe by evaluating a top level form with <kbd>C-M-x</kbd>
3. Afterwards I'd press <kbd>C-x C-z</kbd> to jump back to the REPL and I try out the new code in it
4. I go back to step 2

Basically the Clojure REPL is much more powerful than the Scala REPL and I personally consider it hugely superior to the Scala IDE worksheets. Once you get used to the interactive incremental style of programming Lisp offers everything else starts to look strangely complex by comparison. I'm not familiar with Eclipse's [CounterClockWise](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/) Clojure plugin, but I'm pretty sure it offers similar functionality to Emacs's nREPL.el.

Comment: yes CounterClockWise does this for people who prefer to stay in Eclipse :)

Answer (score 5):

You might want to take a look at the [autoexpect plugin for Leiningen](https://github.com/jakemcc/lein-autoexpect).  Every time you save any file in the working directory, the plugin compiles and runs your code; as a bonus, it will evaluate any "expect" function calls which can serve as tests.  This is very helpful for test driven development and is a nice compliment to working with the REPL as described in the other answer (I often use one or the other or both together depending on how many test cases I have in place).

I should note that running autoexpect is far faster than running "lein test" or "lein run" repeatedly, due to the startup cost of the JVM and Leiningen.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like what you are looking for is the [Clojure Koan plugin](https://github.com/functional-koans/lein-koan). This a worksheet-style problem-solving exercise tool that watches your edits and provides instant feedback on the correctness of your work.

For actual development workflow I second the advice others here have provided on tooling and interactive environment setup, but since you specifically said you are learning Clojure, this can be a fun approach.  There is also a web application called [4Clojure](http://www.4clojure.com/) that you might have fun playing with.

However you will eventually (or right away) want to get a smooth and convenient development environment set up, and I haven't seen any mention so far of a few important tools. One person mentioned Nrepl. If you like Emacs, there's a slime/swank-like interaction mode that jacks into nrepl called [nrepl.el](https://github.com/kingtim/nrepl.el) that provides very nice integration between editing files and messing around in the repl. Similarly there is [VimClojure](https://github.com/vim-scripts/VimClojure), and you can find plugins for IntelliJ ([LaClojure](http://plugins.intellij.net/plugin/?id=4050)) and Eclipse ([Counterclockwise](http://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/)) that are also popular and well-maintained.

Someone mentioned autoexpect. If you are looking for a good TDD setup, I would recommend [midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje). If you are using a 2.0 preview release of leiningen there are a few issues with the [lazytest](https://github.com/stuartsierra/lazytest) integration being in flux, and lazytest itself is or should be deprecated. But I prefer midje over expectations, personally, and these problems will surely be worked out in the 2.0 release of [lein-midje](https://github.com/marick/Midje/wiki/Lein-midje). The stable version of lein-midje that works with the non-preview (1.x) leiningen has autotest-like functionality using lazytest.

Answer (score 0):

As nobody has mentioned it, [cursive](https://cursiveclojure.com/) is really nice these days, although I was sad to move back to a full blown IDE.  You can easily do the same thing as Emacs with the built in repl, just move into the namespace that you are working with and synchronise every time you make changes.  It's a really nice way of working.